# Flutter app not running on iOS 15 targeted device

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0505AE8A-6546-485E-882C-362B1398EC66, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:76A3AE58-960B-4865-B995-DA7D0217CC41, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E81F1D9F-3D1A-418B-B0C5-70F2C9F1E53F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1E721FC3-7A95-4C9D-B1C4-100BC2C5B5CB, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9E868505-526D-488C-A4E7-5192D2F4844A, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:7EDAED36-27CE-4378-8D00-3B997FBF079B, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E281DC44-0C07-424D-A5AD-FFDF8E9E1C03, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E3646822-68A6-4763-A4D4-0D4FA01E5142, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4666A27D-D2C9-4B71-8A99-10313809D903, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:BC18CBF1-A2B5-4EF3-83D4-D76201251872, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AC8D6EAF-7ACE-4DCE-A9F7-9A7730FD0773, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:16D220BE-9C5A-4C37-AA24-9004E901E299, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:6C0E88B4-F179-4DED-A1DF-AE0BD5DC8DE9, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:03DD7CB9-2E69-4905-9C61-3C09D1B24CA7, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4560CAEF-D5EF-44BB-8A2E-DA768836A653, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0EB527B6-6EB7-403B-ACF4-FBE8316834ED, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DDCB0FCF-2727-4FAC-BCB5-8096CA43DA76, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A908BA93-055F-48F7-8FDB-815E8B289AA4, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:94A2FC24-877C-413D-B2B2-14FDAC0A4BE6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E4D5BD61-1CCB-445D-B074-AC5426E90300, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:63559296-EDB2-4341-BD39-0474B173D930, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳

```
Failed to package 
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in parallel
```

Comment: I have same issue are using m1 mac?